# Top navigation not working in magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, navigation, responsive-design

I have integrated 'Argento' theme in Magento with 'autocomplete widget'. But the mobile navigation is not working properly. When I resize the window the navigation togglers display. But if i click on it, it doesn't show the menu. Is this because of any script conflict? Any help will be appreciated.

This is the script in top.phtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    navPro("<?php echo $_id ?>", {
        show_delay: 100,
        hide_delay: 100,
        dropdown_side: "<?php echo $this->getDropdownSide() ?>"
    });
});
new accordion('<?php echo $_id ?>');
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    $('nav-top-toggle').observe('click', function() {
        $('nav-top-toggle').next().toggleClassName('shown');
    });
    new MobileNavigation();

    $('mobile-navigation-toggle').observe('click', function() {
        $('nav-top-toggle').next().toggleClassName('shown');
    });
    $('mobile-search-toggle').observe('click', function() {
        $('search_mini_form').toggleClassName('visible');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you see any error in console?

Comment: It shows no error in script files